# Power BI report published in public mode not refreshing

Tags: powerbi

I have PBI report **published to web (public)** in DirectQuery mode.

Previously it worked like this - refresh in browser (F5) caused refresh of data source (over DQ).

Now it not works! After browser refresh data not been updated from data source.
When I try then same PBI report  using "inside" of PBI account this working properly - after F5 in browser are data source updated ...

Do somebody knows - is there some current changes from Microsoft with DQ functinoality **in PUBLIC mode**?

Thnx Radim